# How to apply EmojiCompat at Android RemoteView(Notification)

Tags: android, notifications, remoteview

I've tried to apply EmojiCompatibility at Notification's RemoteView.

The app crashed when using EmojiTextView at RemoteView(Notification).

```
        <android.support.text.emoji.widget.EmojiTextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

And I also tried another(java code)

```
    EmojiCompat.get().registerInitCallback(new EmojiCompat.InitCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onInitialized() {
            final EmojiCompat compat = EmojiCompat.get();
            remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.tv_name,
            compat.process("item.getEmoticon()");
        }
    });
```

How can I use it at RemoteView?

Error code (when applying EmojiTextView at Layout.)

> couldn’t inflate view for notification
>
> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #39: Error
>   inflating class android.support.text.emoji.widget.EmojiTextView
>
> Couldn't expand RemoteViews for: StatusBarNotification

Comment: add dependency compile "com.android.support:support-emoji:26.0.1"

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use emojicompat for remoteviews.